# Bulk addition in MIPS using stack

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

This is for an university project, I'm clueless on how to work with the stack.

This high level code must be translated into MIPS assembly in a simple way :

```
media(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h){

    return (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h)/8;
}

main(){
    int x;
    x = media (2,4,6,8,10,12,14,19);
}
```

Considering that `a-h` are in `$s0-$s7` , and that it needs to include the code to put the parameters into the stack and to free the it after the return of the procedure.

I'm not necessairly asking for someone to do my homework, just need some light on the matter.

Comment: Allocate memory by subtracting from `$sp`, then address relative to it to access your memory. Finally, add the size back to `$sp` to free it. PS: Doesn't make much sense to use the stack in this case though.

Comment: @Jester thank you, I only need now to know how to stop or pause the program from constantly looping